# How can I manually convert a covariance matrix into a correlation matrix?

Tags: matrix, correlation, covariance

My function for covariance matrix:

```
my_covariance <- function (x=my_data[, c(“attdrug”, “atthouse”, “timedrs”, log10.ltimedrs”, “income”, “emplmnt”, “race”, “mstatus”)]){
cm= colMeans(x)
D = as.matrix(t(x) - cm))
D = t(D)
n=nrow(x)
S = 1/(n-1)*crossprod(D,D)}
```

My code for correlation from the covariance matrix:

```
S = my_covariance()
diag(S)
sqrt(diag(S))
D = 1/sqrt(diag(S))
R = D%*%S%*%D
```

But instead of R giving me a correlation matrix, I get a number? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

Your D is a vector while it should be a diagonal matrix. You can convert it to a diagonal matrix with `D = diag(D)`.

## Solution

Your last two lines should look like these.

```
D = diag(1/sqrt(diag(S)))
R = D%*%S%*%D
```

You can check your solution works correctly by comparing it to the result given by `cov2cor(S)` from R package `stats`.